# How to pull response from a URL and than put said response into a JSON

Tags: javascript, authentication, minecraft

I need to send a request to https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate

and get the response

```
{
    "accessToken": "valid accessToken",
    "clientToken": "client identifier",  

    "selectedProfile": {                 
        "id": "profile identifier",      
        "name": "player name"
    },
    "requestUser": true 
}
```

But I dont know how to ask the server for the out put.

What I need to input is

```
{
  "agent": { "name": "Minecraft", "version": 1 },
  "username": "-email here-",
  "password": "-pass here-"
}
```

That is the data needed to get the token but I can't seem to get the code to ask the server for the token data and than receive it and put it into a JSON.

Comment: Your code format has problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
const postData = async _ => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "agent": { "name": "Minecraft", "version": 1 },
      "username": "-email here-",
      "password": "-pass here-"
    })
  })

  console.log(response)
}
```

This should get the response you need judging by https://wiki.vg/Authentication#Payload this link.